Offline install of Lean
I have fast internet, but my friend, who would like to install Lean on his computer, does not. What should I download to put on a USB stick for him? Any special installation instructions for such an install?

Does your friend also need VS Code on the usb drive?

I started a discussion on this topic on the Lean Zulip: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113488-general/topic/Lean.20on.20a.20thumb.20drive  if there is a good answer it should be posted here.

Software is difficult to install nowadays without the internet.  I don’t know how your friend handles this in general.
For Lean you need the the following:

elan (which fetches you requested version of Lean)
lake and lean (which come from elan)
The mathlib binaries (so you don’t have to compile them yourself)
VS code and the Lean extension

Some of these install (at least in Linux and Mac, I’m not sure about Windows) in your home directory.  Others install in the directory of your Lean project.  So your friend would need a working Lean project including a binary cache, the correct version of lean and lake for this project, and vs code with the lean plug in.
I don’t know how technically savvy you or your friend are?  One suggestion would be to
Use portable VS Code mode.  It lets you put VS Code and the plug ins on a thumb drive.  I don’t know if you could just get by with this and with having a fully set up lean project directory including with the downloaded mathlib cache files.
If not, then docker could be your friend too.  The VS code docker plugin will let you run VS code in docker containers.  You would install Lean in a Docker container (lots of Docker tutorials online) and run Lean from there, using the above installation of VS Code.
(This answer is more brainstorming.  I would write your own answer with a complete set of instructions when you figure it out.)

If both you and your friend are on Windows PCs then the TryLean4Bundle  repository I made on github might be of interest for you. TryLean4Bundle Repo. To use it you can:

Wait for the current build I started to complete (assuming no problems!!), download the executable and put in the flash drive and give it to your friend. Build complete here is the executable: TryLean4Bundle

Clone the repo and run windowsBundle.bat file locally. It will create the bundle locally on your PC. You will find a file named something like TryLean4Bundle_lean4-v4.8.0-rc2_2024-03-06.exe. You can give this to your friend.



The Last Step is;
Your friend runs the executable, it will unpack it self once done your friend will find inside the folder a RunLean.bat file that will start LEAN.

Ingredients
What it basically does is it creates a zipped file containing the necessary ingredients for Lean to run these are:

VSCode (or VSCodium)
Git (in the form of Portable Git)
Lean4 extension for VSCodium
Elan
VC Redistrubatble (to allow Leantar to decompress .tar archives)
Mathematics in Lean just for the user to see something they can get started with.
7z to Compress and Decpmoress everything together.

